# Jenkins custom plugin not able to inject envVar twice in same execution of job

Tags: java, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have been  working on custom plugin which makes a rest call and gets a response back as json, then the plugin inject variables of json as environment variables.

After the new security patch I converted the plugin to use EnvironmentContributingAction which implements the method 
public void buildEnvVars(AbstractBuild arg0, EnvVars env) {
}
to inject env variables in the run.

But I am facing a problem where when the same plugin is used twice in the job, the first instance in the job it executes and inject variables fine.
But the second instance it makes a rest call but doesnt inject the environment Variables.

Any idea why same job instance with same plugin twice cannot inject the environment variables.

NB: This use to work absolutely fine before the new security patch got introduced
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170

Comment: solved by changing the plugin version to 2.x